# Does v8 still have C-style arrays that are contiguous blocks of memory, and how can I make sure I am using them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

There seems to be a conventional wisdom that arrays are represented as hashmaps from indices to values in v8. The only source I found that states otherwise is this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=XAqIpGU8ZZk#t=994s

Seems authoritative, however, it dates back to 2012. A lot could have changed since.

Is it still true that

`var a1 = Array(1000)` is a contiguous array under the hood (unless you exceed array's boundaries) and  `var a2 = []`  is not?

Comment: You're wondering if Google removed optimizations? If you've encountered a situation where an expected optimization seems to be absent, please detail that. There are a number of things that can de-optimize code.

Comment: I am mostly looking for a more recent source. Something must have been published on the subject since 2012.

Comment: I guess the way I see it is that without a specific code problem that could lead one to believe that something has changed for the worse, all a person could do is either speculate that Google isn't inclined to hobble their own code or check the source. Either way, you're not really any better off since in the former case, it technically could be wrong, and in the latter, the source could change tomorrow. No matter what, you're left with simply having to write clear, maintainable code and hope that they continue to implement engines efficiently, which of course they're motivated to do.

Comment: ...so it's either trust someone else's conjecture, keep checking the source on a daily basis, or just trust that software engineers will continue to do what they're highly paid to do.

Answer (score 1):

V8 will use true arrays if it can. For instance, if you fill the array in a contiguous way, don't use `delete` on it, etc. Basically, if you use it as though it were a true array (but one that magically grows for you), V8 is likely to be able to keep using a true array under the covers.

If your data is a fit for one of the [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) (`Int8Array`, `Uint8Array`, `Uint8ClampedArray`, `Int16Array`, `Uint16Array`, `Int32Array`, `Uint32Array`, `Float32Array`, or `Float64Array`), you can use them to *ensure* you're dealing with a true array.

---

Re the comment you added under the question: I don't have a specific reference I can cite for the above. The V8 source code is, of course, available on [the V8 site](https://developers.google.com/v8/), but digging through it for all places where arrays might fall back to dictionary behavior would probably be more work than you (or I) are going to want to do. :-)